# PostgreSQL 8.4 function permissoning - I have to grant public execute otherwise get the error 42501 permisson denied

Tags: postgresql

Connected as a role who is a 'member' of a role which has been granted execute on a function I still get the error:

```
ERROR: 42501: permission denied for function xxx
```

On other functions it is not a problem. I have tried replacing the function and permissions to no avail. The only way I seem to be able to call the function is when I grant the public role  the execute permission on it, which of course is not what I want, esp. since it is a plpythonu function.

I note in pgAdmin the Dependencies tab includes the roles I have granted the execute permission to on the problematic function, whereas with another function (that is working) that has the exact same GRANT's the roles do not show up in the Dependencies tab - whats that about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SECURITY DEFINER was specified on a function that called the function thus calling the function with the owner of the outer function. Removing SECURITY DEFINER from the function definition of the outer function solved the problem.